# How to use clip-path in svg without parsing error?

Tags: svg

I am trying to use clip path as per the example shown here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath
but it just give the error "XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace" What should I do?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <clipPath id="myClip">
    <circle cx="40" cy="35" r="35" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="heart" d="M10,30 A20,20,0,0,1,50,30 A20,20,0,0,1,90,30 Q90,60,50,90 Q10,60,10,30 Z" />
  <use clip-path="url(#myClip)" xlink:href="#heart" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Standalone SVG files must declare namespaces. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: @RobertLongson  Thanks, I had tried one but not both.